# ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not implemented

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am connecting to a .NET web service using java. I am using version 1.6.30, running tomcat 6. I ran the same service using Java 7 and it works fine, but I have to use 1.6.30 because it is the server version. The issue seems similar to the problem found [here](http://glassfish.10926.n7.nabble.com/Accessing-Web-Service-from-JSP-fails-td46902.html), however the link to the workaround doesn't work. I've looked all over for a fix a have been unable to find one.

```
HTTP transport error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not implemented.
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error:     java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not implemented.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:121)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:142)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at $Proxy39.loginSBFE(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I know this is no help at all but recheck your question, people wont understand why a Java version should bother you when calling a .NET Server. According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009237/method-not-implemented-when-calling-a-webservice-on-weblogic-10-3 and this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter4j/f_n5S6luyFg i bet your source is just fine and youre missing a implementation of something which seems to be part of the JDK 7 but was not in JDK 6....

Comment: This probably the same issue with no answer as well....im going to test that now since there are literally hundreds of open questions just about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009237/method-not-implemented-when-calling-a-webservice-on-weblogic-10-3

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution -- I had to add a jar of jaxws-rt 2.2.9 to my pom. This fixed the issue for me.