# Unable to create EC2 instance throw Jclouds2 because of Hibernate sessionfactory

Tags: hibernate, amazon-ec2, sessionfactory, jclouds, hibernate-cache

I have a Java class that uses Jclouds to create Amazon EC2 instances. This code works great and creates EC2 instances when run on stand alone.

But when I am running through my application it is giving me an error, no parameters have been changed and nothing is changed.

When I debug I realized that as soon as my application create a Hibernate SessionFactory, the Java code for EC2 instance creation gives this error.

The problem could be either in some session variables or might be with cache issues.

This is the code where I call the Jclouds class

```
    private BrokerStorage() throws GridBrokerException{
super();
try{
logger.info("Initialising Broker Storage...");
//configures the hibernate system using the hibernate.cfg.xml file
//found in the classpath.

Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure(Constants.BROKER_HIBERNATE_CONFIG);

//build the session factory
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
AWSEC2ComputeService.main(new String[]{"asdf"}); 

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
logger.info("Done: " + (end-start) + " ms.");

cstore = new CredentialStorage();

}catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
throw new GridBrokerException("Error creating storage instance.", e);
 }
 }
```

and below is the code that creates EC2 instances

```
    public class AWSEC2ComputeService implements CreateComputeService {
    private ComputeService compute;

    //private final String NAME = "xxx";
    //private final File keyPairFile = new File(NAME + ".pem");

    private final String provider = "aws-ec2";
    private final String identity = "xxxxx"; 
    private final String credential = "xxxx";
    private final String locationId = Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_2;
    private final String endpoint = "ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com";
    private final String NAME = "xxxx";
    private final String ZONE = Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_2;
    //my imageid
    private final String imageId = "xxxx";

    private final String hardwareId = "xxx";
    private final String securityGroupName = "xxx";
    private final String groupName = "xxx";
    //private final String ZONE = "ap-southeast-2";
    private final int VMnums = 1;

    //MyownerID
    private final String imageOwnerId = "xxxx";
    private final String keyPairName = "xxxx";
    private float bidPrice = 0.1f;
    private Set<NodeMetadata>  launchedNodes = new HashSet<NodeMetadata>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AWSEC2ComputeService jcloudsNova = new AWSEC2ComputeService();

        try {
             jcloudsNova.createComputeService();
             jcloudsNova.createInstances();
             jcloudsNova.finalize();
             jcloudsNova.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            jcloudsNova.close();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public ComputeService getComputeService() {
        return compute;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> createInstances(){  
        System.out.println("entering create instances");

        Template template = null;

        try {

        // Create a template for the VM
        template = compute.
                templateBuilder().
                locationId(locationId).
                imageId(imageId).osFamily(OsFamily.UBUNTU).hypervisorMatches("paravirtual").
                hardwareId(hardwareId).build();

        /*template = compute.
                templateBuilder().
                locationId(locationId).
                imageId(imageId).
                hardwareId(hardwareId).build();*/

        // Specify your own security group
        TemplateOptions options = template.getOptions();
        options.securityGroups(securityGroupName);
        options.as(AWSEC2TemplateOptions.class).keyPair(NAME).spotPrice(bidPrice);

        if(template != null){
            System.out.println("template: " + template.toString());
        }



            Method method = options.getClass().getMethod("keyPair", String.class);
            method.invoke(options, keyPairName);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        final List<String> launchedNodesAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            // Launch the instances...
            Set<? extends NodeMetadata> launchedNodesMetadata = compute.createNodesInGroup(groupName, VMnums, template);  

           // Collect the addresses ...
            for (NodeMetadata nodeMetadata : launchedNodesMetadata) {
                System.out.println("Node id: " + nodeMetadata.getId() + " HostName " + nodeMetadata.getHostname() + " Pub Addrs "+nodeMetadata.getUri());
                Set<String> privateAddresses = nodeMetadata.getPrivateAddresses();
                for(String address : privateAddresses){
                    launchedNodesAddresses.add(address);
                }
            }
            launchedNodes.addAll(launchedNodesMetadata);
        } catch (RunNodesException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Nodes could not be created.", e);
        }
        return launchedNodesAddresses;
    }



    public Location getLocation(){
            Location loca = null;
          System.out.println(">Ec2: List Locations.");
          ComputeService client = compute;

          Set<? extends Location> listLocations = client.listAssignableLocations();
          List<Location> locationList=new ArrayList<Location>();
          for (  Location loc : listLocations) {
              System.out.println("Locationsadsfs : " + loc.toString());
                  if(loc.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(locationId)){
                  System.out.println("Location : " + loc.toString());
                  loca = loc;
                  }
          }
          System.out.println(">EC2: Location List obtained successfully.");
          return loca;
    }

    @Override
    public ComputeService createComputeService() {

        Properties imageOwnerIdFilter = new Properties();
        imageOwnerIdFilter.setProperty(
            "jclouds.ec2.ami-query", "owner-id=" +
            imageOwnerId +
            ";state=available;image-type=machine;virtualization-type=paravirtual;");

        compute = ContextBuilder.
                newBuilder(provider).
                //endpoint(endpoint).
                credentials(identity, credential).
                overrides(imageOwnerIdFilter).
                buildView(ComputeServiceContext.class).getComputeService();
        return compute;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyAllInstance() {
        Iterator<NodeMetadata> iterator = launchedNodes.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            NodeMetadata nodeMetadata = iterator.next();
            destroyInstance(nodeMetadata.getId());
        }

    }    

    public void destroyInstance(String nodeId){     
        compute.destroyNode(nodeId);
    }

    public void suspendInstance(String nodeId){
        compute.suspendNode(nodeId);
    }

    public void rebootInstance(String nodeId){
        compute.rebootNode(nodeId);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            Closeables.close(compute.getContext(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //must write logger statement
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And the Error I get is the following

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not implemented.
    at java.net.URLStreamHandler.openConnection(URLStreamHandler.java:97)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1020)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.initConnection(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:208)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.convert(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:153)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.convert(JavaUrlHttpCommandExecutorService.java:72)
    at org.jclouds.http.internal.BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.invoke(BaseHttpCommandExecutorService.java:95)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.invoke(InvokeHttpMethod.java:90)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.internal.InvokeHttpMethod.apply(InvokeHttpMethod.java:44)
    at org.jclouds.reflect.FunctionalReflection$FunctionalInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FunctionalReflection.java:117)
    at com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.describeRegions(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.suppliers.DescribeRegionsForRegionURIs.get(DescribeRegionsForRegionURIs.java:47)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.suppliers.DescribeRegionsForRegionURIs.get(DescribeRegionsForRegionURIs.java:34)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:57)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:119)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.derived.RegionIdsFromRegionIdToURIKeySet.get(RegionIdsFromRegionIdToURIKeySet.java:49)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.derived.RegionIdsFromRegionIdToURIKeySet.get(RegionIdsFromRegionIdToURIKeySet.java:36)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$SupplierComposition.get(Suppliers.java:67)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:57)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:119)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.RegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(RegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:56)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:71)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:46)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:73)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:57)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:119)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.locationId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:618)
    at cloudResourceBroker.AWSEC2ComputeService.createInstances(AWSEC2ComputeService.java:100)
    at cloudResourceBroker.AWSEC2ComputeService.main(AWSEC2ComputeService.java:68)
    at org.gridbus.broker.common.BrokerStorage.<init>(BrokerStorage.java:67)
    at org.gridbus.broker.common.BrokerStorage.initialise(BrokerStorage.java:86)
    at org.gridbus.broker.common.Broker.initialise(Broker.java:122)
    at org.gridbus.broker.common.Broker.<init>(Broker.java:86)
    at org.gridbus.workflow.maria.BrokerInstantiation.InstantiateBroker(BrokerInstantiation.java:55)
    at org.gridbus.workflow.maria.BrokerInstantiation.getBrokerInstance(BrokerInstantiation.java:74)
    at org.gridbus.workflow.maria.BrokerInstantiation.runApplication(BrokerInstantiation.java:176)
    at org.gridbus.workflow.maria.BrokerInstantiation.main(BrokerInstantiation.java:195)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application is loading an implementation of the `URLStreamHandler` that does not support proxies. Checkout this and see if you are facing the same issue:
[Method not implemented when calling a WebService on Weblogic 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009237/method-not-implemented-when-calling-a-webservice-on-weblogic-10-3)